# FileMaker Pro version control with Git in Beanstalk / Github / Bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, filemaker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We currently use Subversion for version control of our FileMaker development, but we're starting to explore moving to Git instead. We've heard some rumors of people experiencing file corruption when using Git for FileMaker files, but I haven't been able to track down any real sources.

Is anyone using Git for version control of FileMaker Pro files? Other than needing to close the files completely before committing, have you had any issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used both Git and Subversion for version control with FileMaker files. Chris makes some good points about size restrictions, but there are ways of making the best when using git.

### Version control file corruption with FileMaker

I suspect that the file corruption that the rumors come from are not coming from git usage specifically, but from how the user is interacting with the files while using git.

When you have a FileMaker file open, the FileMaker client is interacting directly with the binary file itself. Data and structure are being read and written to while the file is active, so if you try to commit the file during that process you're going to risk corruption. This risk is the same for both Git and Subversion.

Whenever you're working with FileMaker files and version control, you need to make sure you close the file out before you commit. You don't necessarily need to close FileMaker itself out, but the file needs to be closed.

Also, make sure the file is truly closed. You could think the file is closed and have a hidden or offscreen window open. Go to the Window menu and make sure all of the windows are closed before committing.

### File Size

You can definitely use git for FileMaker files, but you are going to run into those size restrictions if you're pushing to a public remote hosting provider. That said, if you have your own local git server then maybe size isn't an issue.

The best bet when dealing with size in the repository is to commit clones to your repository. If you're working from a FileMaker Server you can use backup schedules with cloning enabled to spit them out easily. This also get's around the open file issue because you would be committing a cloned backup, not the active file.

It can be a pain because now all of your data is out of the file and FileMaker doesn't have a good built in automation for bringing data back in, but you can build a transporter file that runs imports from your populated files (outside of version control) into your clones (in version control). We do that for almost every project in my company.

When it comes down to it, the important thing to keep track of in your version control is the structure and not the data itself. Storing clones should cut down on the file size enough to make either version control system viable.

Comment: This answer is correct, but to amplify, FileMaker files are always open for writing as long as they're open in the database. They must be properly closed before they are safe to be copied by another process. You should only commit files while they are *not* open in FileMaker.

Answer (score 4):

I have no experience with FileMaker, but Git is very good at maintaining the integrity of the things you commit. (Yes, you may need to exit the application to ensure that things are in a consistent state before you commit, but that's a FileMaker thing, not a Git thing.)

However, if FileMaker files are (a) binary or (b) large, you may want to keep looking. Many of Git's features are designed around working with text files, and large files of any type can cause repository size and performance to suffer. I wouldn't use it to version Access databases, for example.

Note also that hosted Git providers often have maximum file sizes for files and repositories.

For example, GitHub currently sets quotas at [100MB per file, 1GB per repository](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/#rule-of-thumb-1gb-per-repository-100mb-per-file). On that same page they also explicitly [recommend against storing database dumps](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/#database-dumps), which are often very large text files.

Bitbucket has a [soft 1GB repository limit and a hard 2GB repository limit](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action;jsessionid=69008E0A1C3B93E141898113217F0C5C.node1?pageId=273877699).

Answer (score 1):

You can save clones of your Filemaker file into your Git repo. This will circumvent Git restrictions for all but exceedingly large databases, and avoid the problem of unclosed files being written to the repo ("corruption").